# Can Percy Jackson see under deep water?

Tags: percy-jackson

I know that after 1000 meters there is no light under the sea. Could Percy Jackson see in the dark, if he was under the water?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the Percy Jackson would require to see so deep underwater, or if he could see in the dark above water? What exactly is it you're trying to solve? How did this question come to mind? These are some interesting details that can help add to your question and make it a bit more stimulating, as opposed to just being a random thought.

Answer (score 21):

## Yes, he has some limited underwater vision.

This is made clear by a quote in *The Last Olympian*:

> Beyond this, the sea floor stretched into gloom. I could see battles raging—flashes of energy, explosions, the glint of armies clashing. **A regular human would've found it too dark to see**. Heck, a regular human would've been crushed by the pressure and frozen by the cold. Even my heat-sensitive eyes couldn't make out exactly what was going on.
> <sub>*Percy Jackson and the Olympians*, book 5: *The Last Olympian*, chapter 2: "I Meet Some Fishy Relatives" (emphasis added)</sub>

So while he can't see perfectly underwater, he does have some limited special vision.

Comment: "heat-sensitive eyes" I'm triggered. Water is basically opaque in the Infrared. His heat vision would be completely blind after just a couple feet underwater.

Comment: @Shufflepants It works for him, because magic!

Comment: @Shufflepants technically, it's not claiming that its' the heat-sensitivity of the eyes that's allowing it.  It's just describing how well they work and incidentally mentioning their sensitivity to heat.

Comment: @Shufflepants Yeah, that's what he said "my heat-sensitive eyes couldn't make out ... what was going on"

Comment: Because of the sentence before "A regular human would've found it too dark to see." And with the whole sentence "Even my heat-sensitive eyes couldn't make out exactly what was going on." To me, implied that the only reason he could see anything at all, just barely, was because of his heat-vision. @Forral Then why not say "my magic eyes", or "my true-sight eyes", or "my eyes of Zeus" instead of "my heat-sensitive eyes" >.<

Answer (score 2):

Not only can Percy see better underwater than regular mortals, but he can also sense the presence of many things when they are underwater, as though he has the ability to use sonar.

> I should've been blind, too,
>   this deep in the water at night, but I could see the heat from living forms, and the cold of the
>   currents. It's hard to describe. **It wasn't like regular seeing, but I could tell where everything
>   was.** 
>   *Percy Jackson and the Titan's Curse* -- Chapter 8: I Make a Dangerous Promise

Comment: Do you have any evidence this is indeed the case you can [edit] in?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I have added a quote from The Titan's Curse.